# How to do audit log for php webpage and mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

My webpage is coded with PHP and is linked to MySQL Server Management Studio database. The main function of this webpage is to allow users to search for data in  the database through this webpage. I would like to create a search log to track users activity (who, what, when did they searched, and what result did they get). How can I do that?

For admin, they have permission rights to add, delete, edit data from the database tables. I would like to create an audit log to capture the datetime, userid, old value , new value and field etc that was added, deleted or edited.

As I am new to these, appreciate all help from everyone. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just create a table to track the data? Then just create columns for whatever you want to store on each search. Then everytime someone searches just insert the details into that table. Other than that, we are here to help solve coding problems based on original code. I'd suggest having a go at that; and then coming back here with an actual problem and not a premise for an idea.

Comment: have you looked at special for these case libraries like ELK - https://www.elastic.co/de/elk-stack ?

Answer (score 1):

Building your own audit trail can have hidden issues and caveats

1. Logging details about new and/or old value can have negative impact on your DB and server - say you're trying to save dozens of audit records in second while fields updated are huge blob or text fields. Thus think about data truncating for audit purposes or audit only necessary.
2. Think about auditing MORE details than you want now. Possible additional audit fields can include IP address for example.
3. Think about auditing searching/viewing also - it's also can helpful whether user just searched for something.

Suppose this structure will do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_trail (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    user_id int not null,
    action_time datetime not null,
    action_performed enum ('view','add', 'edit', 'delete'),
    table_affected varchar(50) not null, -- table of affected item
    item_affected int not null, -- supposing every table has it's own id key
    old_value varchar(1000), 
    new_value varchar(1000)
)
```

How to store old and new values - it's your decision. First think that custom audit log IS NOT suited for restoring back values (mysqldump and other utilities come to the rescue). But often it's enough to store short string representation of old and new values (that's why varchar)

Comment: this confirms my approach, but about the old and new value, is there any benefit using varchar over text?

Comment: @digout, I didn't found any possible performance caveats for TEXT vs VARCHAR - both can indexed for full-text search, they require space on disk based on data actual size. Well, only performance tests can show the difference in your case. Besides you can start with VARCHAR and alter records for TEXT records based on your needs, it's your choice after all.